# Why happens redirect to strange page via proxy_pass request

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, proxy, proxypass

I'm settings VPN server (amazon AWS), that will redirect all requests from my server to api endpoints in some e-commerce service, that is blocked in my county.

My config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.test.com.br;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://api.tiendanube.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

So, just grab everything and redirect to some endpoint.

So, everything works fine. But if i need call api from e-commerce server 2 or 3 times during the single request, i got 404 error from page - that contains html with words **Cision** and **MultiVu**. I think this some web-site like https://www.multivu.com

I have no idea, what it is the service, and why i got redirect to this web-site.

When i do request without proxy to e-commerce service api (as many times as required during single request) all works fine.

When i tried to make tcpdump - i saw, that i got this strange page before i reach e-commerce api.

So, I have no idea, what is going on and why i got this strange behavior. Can someone suggest me, what can i check else?

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault rather than StackOverflow. The answer is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1042143/nginx-proxy-requests-to-external-server-during-dns-transition). Looks somewhat strange that you don't know such a basic things and use that kind of copy-paste while being able to use `tcpdump` :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i understand. Nginx resolve adress during reload of config. E-commerce system change their IP, so my proxy call old IP, which was occupied by another site.

Reload nginx solve my problem.